# How to toggle two views with slide animation ios autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two views. View 1 and View 2. I have a toggle which I want to animate between view 1 and view 2.

Right now I have view 1 acting as the base layer and view 2 should animate on and off above that as if it were floating. Using visual format strings I have something like this:

```
.. @"H:|[view1]|" ..
.. @"V:|[view1]|" ..
.. @"V:|[view2]|" ..
```

then to show or hide view 2 I have

```
_showView2 = ..@"H:|[view2]|" ..
_hideView2 = ..@"H:|[view2(==0)]|";
```

This works, but I don't really want to scale the bounds of view 2, I want it to slide in over view 1 from offscreen with it's final fixed width.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to do this programatically. Is there a simple way to define this layout with visual formatting? What's the best way to achieve this? I'm laying out my views entirely with code.